# nav-tabs aninhada

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, nav-bar

Amigos tenho uma nav-bar que é chama um nav-tabs1 e gostaria que nela houvesse outra nav-tabs2 só que ao inserir todas as opções que são chamadas depois pela nav-bar não ficar na nav-tab1, ela é aberta vazia e vai para nav-tab2.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <p>To make the tabs toggleable, add the data-toggle="tab" attribute to each link. Then add a .tab-pane class with a unique ID for every tab and wrap them inside a div element with class .tab-content.</p>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
     <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#principal">Principal</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1.1">Menu 1.1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1.2">Menu 1.2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1.3">Menu 1.3</a></li>
  </ul>

      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="menu1.1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1.1</h3>
      <p>TESTANDO ACESSO AO MENU 1.1.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="menu1.2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1.2</h3>
      <p>TESTANDO ACESSO AO MENU 1.2.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1.3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1.3</h3>
      <p>TESTANDO ACESSO AO MENU 1.3.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Carlos sem seu HTML/CSS não existe a mínima possibilidade de alguém conseguir te responder. Por favor edite sua pergunta com o código que vc já tem pronto. Tb sugiro vc fazer um Tour para ver como a plataforma funciona https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Certo, já fiz o tour e não encontrei perguntas a respeito, quanto ao código realmente foi um ato falho.

Comment: Não leve a mal, foi só um comentário, as vezes só escrevendo pode parecer rude, mas não foi. É que sem o seu código e lendo a pergunta não tem como te responder, nem montar um exemplo que possa te ajudar entende. []´s

Comment: Tudo bem hugocsl, entendo. Agradeço a ajuda cara.

Comment: Viu que como com o código fica melhor para responder :D, se tiver alguma dúvida é só falar

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que eu entendi o que voce precisa seria isso como abaixo:

PS1: não utilize "." para seletor de ID, ele pode ser quebrado no css e no js.
 PS2: Organize melhor o código, comentários e identações para separar sessões do site podem ser úteis quando se tem mais de um elemento do mesmo tipo coexisitindo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <p>To make the tabs toggleable, add the data-toggle="tab" attribute to each link. Then add a .tab-pane class with a unique ID for every tab and wrap them inside a div element with class .tab-content.</p>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
     <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#principal">Principal</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1a">Menu 1.1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1b">Menu 1.2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1c">Menu 1.3</a></li>
  </ul>


      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

<div id="menu1a" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 1.1</h3>
        <p>TESTANDO ACESSO AO MENU 1.1.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="menu1b" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 1.2</h3>
        <p>TESTANDO ACESSO AO MENU 1.2.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1c" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 1.3</h3>
        <p>TESTANDO ACESSO AO MENU 1.3.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    
    
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Michel não era apenas problema com os IDs, repare que o seu segundo level de Tabs continua não funcionando, mesmo vc mudando o nome dos Ids as Tab internas não "linkam"....

Comment: Sim, eu havia esquecido de colar o grupo de conteudo da div, a unica cois que vc precisa fazer é organizar onde vai ficar o texto p que está entre os tabs e o conteudo das tabs.